# Avoid DoS attacks on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a small question with possibly a complex answer. I have tried to research around, but I think I may not know the keywords.

I want to build a web service that will send a JSON response, which would be used for another application. My goal is having the App Engine server crawl a set of webpages and store the relevant values so the second application (client) would not need to query everything. It will only go to my server with the already condensed information.

I know, it's pretty common, but how can I defend from attackers who wish to exhaust my App Engine resources/quota?
I have been thinking on limiting the amount of requests by IP (say.. 200 requests / 5 minutes), but is that feasible? Or is there a better, and more clever way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to cache the JSON. don't hit the datastore for every request. use memcache or possibly, depending on your requirements, you can cache the JSON in a static file in Cloud Storage. This simple is the best defender against DDOS, since every request adds minimal overhead.

Also, take a look in the DDOS protection service offered by app engine:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/dos

Answer (score 0):

You could require users to log-in then generate and send an auth key to the client app that must accompany any requests to the app engine service.